# Specify first character of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input where I want the first character to be `#`.
That means if the user writes something, it automatically adds the `#`, or better, the `#` is already present in the input.

How do I do that? I thought i could do that with `jQuery` mask but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: if you want by default in the `text` you should have set `value` like `<input type="text" value="#"  >` but problem if they delete you can't get this again.

Comment: I'm guessing you'd want this for a hex code input?  If so would you also require the restriction of characters to 6 (7 including the `#`)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code,

```js
$("#your-input-id").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 8) {
        var text = this.value;
        if (text.length == 0) {
            this.value = text + '#';
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#">
  <input id="your-input-id"  type="text" placeholder="Type a text here..." data-prefix="#" />
</form>
```

Hope this will work.

This will append `#` when you will start typing, and it will append everything later to `#`.

**EDIT**

```
$("#your-input-value").keydown(function(e) {
    var cur_val=$(this).val();
    var field=this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if(field.value.indexOf('#') !== 0) {
            $(field).val(cur_val);
        } 
    }, 1);
});
```

Comment: This works nicely for the default situation, but it is possible to get an input without the initial `#` (e.g. Enter text, select all text, enter text) Depending on the desired use, this may or may not be important.

Comment: use prefix text then, while saving, just append # to the string.

Comment: Yep, I'm just pointing out a possible flaw to try and stop anyone bumping into it later.

Answer (score 0):

See this solution http://codepen.io/bachors/pen/yeJOrg

Running example to meet your needs:

```js
/***********************************************
* #### jQuery Prefix Input ####
* Coded by Ican Bachors 2015.
* http://ibacor.com/labs/jquery-prefix-input/
* Updates will be posted to this site.
***********************************************/

$(".yourClass").focus(function(){var a=$(this).data("prefix"),ibacor_currentId=$(this).attr('id'),ibacor_val=$(this).val();if(ibacor_val==''){$(this).val(a)}ibacor_fi(a.replace('ibacorat',''),ibacor_currentId);return false});function ibacor_fi(d,e){$('#'+e).keydown(function(c){setTimeout(function(){var a=bcr_riplis($('#'+e).val()),qq=bcr_riplis(d),ibacor_jumlah=qq.length,ibacor_cek=a.substring(0,ibacor_jumlah);if(a.match(new RegExp(qq))&&ibacor_cek==qq){$('#'+e).val(bcr_unriplis(a))}else{if(c.key=='Control'||c.key=='Backspace'||c.key=='Del'){$('#'+e).val(bcr_unriplis(qq))}else{var b=bcr_unriplis(qq)+c.key;$('#'+e).val(b.replace("undefined",""))}}},50)})}function bcr_riplis(a){var f=['+','$','^','*','?'];var r=['ibacorat','ibacordolar','ibacorhalis','ibacorkali','ibacortanya'];$.each(f,function(i,v){a=a.replace(f[i],r[i])});return a}function bcr_unriplis(a){var f=['+','$','^','*','?'];var r=['ibacorat','ibacordolar','ibacorhalis','ibacorkali','ibacortanya'];$.each(f,function(i,v){a=a.replace(r[i],f[i])});return a}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#">
  <input id="yourInput" class="yourClass" type="text" placeholder="Type a text here..." data-prefix="#" />
</form>
```

Comment: Remark the ** data-prefix="#" *** in the input element

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="txtUrl" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.txtContent').keydown(function(e) {
     var cur_val = $(this).val(); 
    if(cur_val.length == 0) {
      $(this).val('#' + cur_val);
    }
});
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jMH9b/43/

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is almost same answer as mine.

Comment: @VforVendetta Sorry mate!.. I didn't notice.. I was busy drafting the answer.

Comment: Yeah.. It is *almost*... not *completely*

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, if there is already a **SLASH** it should not do anything. Here is the solution

```js
$('#description').bind('input', function(event){
  var currentVal = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(currentVal.indexOf('#') !== 0 ? ('#' + currentVal) : currentVal)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label name="description">Enter some text</label>
<input type="text" id="description" name="description">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id='e' onKeyup='test(this)' value='#'/>

var input = document.getElementById('e');

function  test(e){
input.value = e.value.charAt(0) !== '#' ? input.value = '#' + e.value : e.value
}
```

hope this helps...